# Connect to SQL CE and send data to remote server through API request

Tags: c#, php, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I work on PHP but have encountered a situation where I need to pull data from an .sdf file and send it to a web application which is built on Laravel . I am finding it very difficult or almost impossible to read .sdf using PHP. I have very short time to work on it.  So, I want to write a small program in C# that will do the followings

1. Will  connect to the sdf file.
2. Run a query and fetch the data.
3. Send the data to a remote server in JSON format using POST method.

I know its going to be very easy and I wish I had known a little C#.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Use a ASP.NET Web API template

Create objects representing the json response

Use ADO.NET with System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll and SqlCeConnection to connect and query the database, and populate your response objects.

For even faster development, you could use LINQ to SQL